# Instafeed js, which div to render instafeed

Tags: javascript, html, instafeedjs

Hi guys I am currently working with `instafeed.js` and I am trying to figure out if it is possible to determine inside which `div` the images should be rendered:

Right now I just use the standard `<div id="instafeed"></div>`, but I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
<div id="instafeed-1">Instagram feed with a specific tag</div>
<div id="instafeed-2">Instagram feed with a specific user</div>
<div id="instafeed-3">Instagram feed with a different configuration</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify another id by using the target option. For example :

`var feed = new Instafeed({
        target: 'instafeed-1',
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'awesome',
        clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
    });
    feed.run();`

Please refer to docs for more options:https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/blob/master/README.md#standard-options